# Why can't bash assign the contents of this file to a variable?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed

File: test.txt (yes, just those 4 characters)

```
@(:/
```

Bash script file: test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get the entire content
content=`cat ./test.txt`
echo $content
```

I'm running this version of bash on Ubuntu (this works fine on OS X but I need it to work on Ubuntu)

Bash Version:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

Ubuntu version:

```
Linux vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 3.13.0-66-generic #108-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 7 15:20:27 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It's annoying as hell because bash just hangs and never completes. Really curious to know if there are some rules I'm just not familiar with for certain versions of Bash.

Also, if you don't have the exact same version and it works fine for you, please don't post and say "It worked fine for me". The point of this post is not to hear how great it works for you under completely different circumstances. The point is to understand why it doesn't work under these very specific circumstances.

Comment: Did you try : `content=$(cat ./test.txt)` ?

Comment: Does it work if you remove any of the characters? Have you checked for any special characters in the file?

Comment: Not reproducible.  Are you sure there isn't a DOS line ending at the tail of the file?  Does it help if you fix the quoting -- `echo "$content"`?

Comment: When you say that bash "hangs", what is it doing?  I suggest you run `strace -f bash test.sh` to see what it is waiting for.  If you don't have access to `strace` then at least run it with a trace `bash -x test.sh` to see which statement is hanging.

Comment: Have you tried with another file (maybe just `abc` in it)? Does it do the same? If you remove the echo or quote the variable (i.e. `echo "${content}"`) does it still hang? If you run `od -x test.txt` you should see `2840 2f3a 000a` - anything else might indicate control characters.

Comment: @Till Exhibits the same behavior with that syntax.

Comment: @tripleee There is not a DOS line ending. This is just a brand new text file where I type those specific characters, But echo "$content" seemed to do the trick!

Comment: @cdarke the strace also hung when I attempted to echo that variable with that specific combination of characters, but when I wrapped the echo in quotes, everything was fine.

`bash -x ./test.sh 
++ cat ./test.txt
+ content='@(:/'
`

Comment: @Component10 `od -x test.txt 
0000000 2840 2f3a 000a
0000005
`

Comment: @BillButler, ...so you have NULs in your file -- that makes it very different from what your question described. Incidentally, the output from your `echo` will **certainly** not contain those NULs, so your code isn't behaving the same way the original did even as given in the answer (though the differences will be invisible on many terminals): bash uses C strings, which are NUL-delimited, and thus literally unable to represent NUL characters in their contents.

Comment: I hate to start a pissing match here, but I simply typed 4 characters into a text file @CharlesDuffy and then saved the file.

    `vi test.txt
    @(:/`

Then :wq! to save it

Comment: @BillButler, ...hmm. Is the `0000005` perhaps on a different line, thus being a position marker rather than content with NULs? It's hard to read things correctly when they're squashed together.

Comment: ...the way I tend to avoid that kind of ambiguity in StackOverflow comments, btw, is to put each line in its own backticket code segment; thus: `od -x test.txt`, `0000000 2840 2f3a 000a`, `0000005`.

Comment: ...incidentally, even with the newlines specified, that output from `od -x` is still a bit misleading: Since it's outputting shorts rather than bytes, it puts a NULL in the MSB place for the last short in the file, even when that NUL isn't really there in the content. Better to use `hexdump -C`, which doesn't have that kind of misbehavior, if your OS provides it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the great comments. While I still don't know the reason for the problem, it's pretty clear that it's important to quote bash variables when they might contain unexpected text combinations. In this case, the solution from @tripleee worked properly.

Properly working script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get the entire content
content=$(cat ./test.txt)
echo "$content"
```

Comment: It should be said that `read -r content < ./test.txt` will do the job quite well without invoking the external program  `cat` (which is notorious for mis-use).